# Printing entries in a dictionary in descending order

Tags: python

Printing entries in a dictionary in descending order so that I can view them according to the example

08:02 - registration

08:45 - doctor checkup

09:00 - procedure

09:15 - doctor checkup

09:25 - radiography

10:30 - blood test

11:00 - doctor checkup

11:30 - hospital discharge

```
class Time():
    def __init__(self, hour, minutes):
        self.hour = hour
        self.minutes = minutes

    def __str__(self):
        return "%02d:%02d" % (self.hour, self.minutes)

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.minutes == 0:
            return 'Time({0},{1}0)'.format(self.hour, self.minutes)
        return 'Time({0},{1})'.format(self.hour, self.minutes)
    
class Event():
    def __init__(self, time, nameStattion):
        self.time = time
        self.nameStattion = nameStattion

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}-{1}".format(self.time, self.nameStattion)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Event(Time(%d,%d),"%s")' % (self.time.hour, self.time.minutes, self.nameStattion)
    
class MedicalRecord():
    data = {}

    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id

    def __repr__(self):
       return 'Event(Time(%d,%d),"%s")' % (self.time.hour, self.time.minutes, self.nameStattion)

    def add(self, time, station):
        self.data[time] = Event(Time(int(time[0:2]), int(time[3:5])), station)

    def view(self):
        #for i in range(len(self.data)):
            print(eval(repr(self.data)))

time1 = Time(8, 2)
time1
print(time1)
time2 = eval(repr(time1))
print(time2)
event1 = Event(time1, 'registration')
event1
event2 = eval(repr(event1))
print(event2)
record1 = MedicalRecord('David', 1)
record1.add('08:02', 'registration')
print(record1.data)
record1.add('09:15','doctor checkup')
record1.add('08:45','doctor checkup')
record1.add('09:00','procedure')
record1.add('11:00','doctor checkup')
record1.add('09:25','radiography')
record1.add('11:30','hospital discharge')
record1.add('10:30','blood test')
record1.view()
```

In my example it prints as one side list

Comment: Why is the for-loop commented out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sort a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use the python [sorted()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sorted.asp) function. It will have a key argument which you can pass a function that returns the time and python will sort the list according to that. From there you will probably get an ascending list which you can just do list.reverse() to make it descending.

Edit: actully sorted lets you choose if its acending or decending using the "reverse" argument. See the sorted link for more info.

```
def keyFunc(EventObj): return f'{EventObj.time}' 
sortedList = sorted(SomeEventList, key=keyFunc, reversed = True)
```

Comment: And how do you write it in code?

Comment: See my edited response above for an example

Answer (score 0):

```
    def view(self):
        for key in sorted(self.data):
            print(key, '-', self.data[key])
```